# About Activity's life cycle

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static IReceiveMessage iReceiveMessage;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       iReceiveMessage.receiveMessage(intent.getStringExtra("message"));
}       
public static void setReceiveMessage(IReceiveMessage iReceiveMessage1) {
    iReceiveMessage = iReceiveMessage1;
}}

public interface IReceiveMessage {
public void receiveMessage(String message);
}




public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IReceiveMessage{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);
              MyReceiver.setReceiveMessage(this);

}
     @Override
public void onReceiverMessage(String message) {
Log.i("test", message);

}
}
```

why Mainactivity still receive messages from MyReciever after it was exited?

Comment: When MainAcitiy is destroyed,why MyReceiver can still send a message to it through IReceiveMessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unregister your Activity in onDestroy():

```
protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      MyReceiver.setReceiveMessage(null);
}
```

Comment: I did't unregister it,but i still receive the message from MyReceiver;

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: When MyReceiver receiver a Broadcast,onReceive will be called and MainActiviy will receive a message. when MainAcitviy is destoryed,it will not receive this message because it's rcycled by gc. but in my case MainAcitvity received this message. why?

Comment: Because you still have the static reference. It is nor recycled by gc.  That's why I told you to unset the receiver.

Comment: you mean the activity is not destroyed? but when I exit the program the onDestroy method have been called.

Comment: Right, but there is still your reference to the java class. That's why the GC can not free the memory.

Comment: but still not accepting the answer?